# IF statements for numbers between values

Tags: excel

I have a cell in Excel that works out BMI from height and weight.  I was thinking of a VLOOKUP from a table of BMI values but now I've seen that there are ranges of values:

less than 18.5 - underweight
18.5-24.99 - healthy
25.00-29.99 - overweight
30+ - obese

Could a nested IF work?

Answer (score 3):

You could do either one, vlookup or nested it.  I'll show a vlookup though since it will be a little more clear than nested if statements.  Set up three columns, with the left two columns being your min/max BMI values, and the third the description.

Then use a vlookup: `=VLOOKUP(E1,$A$1:$C$4,3,TRUE)`

For example:

[image]

Note that you can't use `18.5` twice, or else you'll get "Healthy" or "Underweight" only...so that's why I have `18.4999` instead.  If you want "Underweight" to show `0 to 18.50` though, you can just edit the amount of decimals to show.  Select cell B1, then go to Format -> Number -> and in "Decimal Places" put `2`.

Also, isntead of doing `1000000` for the Obese Max, you can leave it blank and it should still work with numbers >= 30.

Edit per @pnuts: You don't need column B at all! If you remove it, this will be the formula: `=VLOOKUP(D1,$A$1:$B$4,2,TRUE)`...learned that myself, thanks pnuts!

Comment: I think OP wants it to work even if one types in 26?

Comment: It works for me if you put `26` in E1, it resolves to "Overweight"...does it not for you?

Comment: Ah. True for last argument. Ignore me XD

Comment: @pnuts - Oh woah, I didn't know that! Thanks for that tip, I've updated my OP. Nice!

Comment: What @BruceWayne said.

Comment: That is great, thanks.  I'm not sure I understand why it works but it does! I was making it much more complicated trying to use nested IFs with too many arguments and trying to get BETWEEN (if possible!) into it!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a VLookUp, If you want to use a nested if, you could use the AND function as follows:

[image: excel nested if]

What's happening here is a table, with the range spread out between min and max for the ranges, with the descriptor. Then the BMI (F) column is analysed against the min, max columns (A, B) and if it is a range (like the middle rows) the AND method is used with if to check all conditions are true. If there is only 1 condition (under 18.5 or equal to or over 30) then no AND is needed.